# Meaning of the angle between eigenvector and gradient

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am currently trying to adapt a technique to find numerically first order saddle points on an energy surface for many degrees of freedom. The starting point is a point $\vec{P}\in\mathbb{R}^N$ where the hessian $H_P$ has at least 1 negative eigenvalue. The idea is now that we minimize a modified force $\vec{F}_P^{m}$. This force is obtained by inverting the component of the force along the direction of the eigenvector $\vec{v}_0$ corresponding to the lowest eigenvalue of the hessian. Therefore:
$$
\vec{F}_P^{m} = \vec{F} - 2(\vec{F}\cdot \vec{v}_0)\vec{v}_0,
$$
where $\vec{F}$ is the original force. This is alright as long as the dot-product $\vec{F}\cdot \vec{v}_0$ is sufficiently large. Otherwise minimizing $\vec{F}_P^m$ yields the same result as minimizing $\vec{F}$ and the search will head to the next energy minimum instead of a first order saddle point. In other words if the eigenvector $\vec{v}_0$ is perpendicular to the gradient (or force) calculating $\vec{F}_P^m$ is not sufficient. Unfortunately I obtain exactly this situation for many interesting starting points of my energy surfaces. As starting points I prefer points where only 1 eigenvalue is negative but the rest is positive (but I can't ensure this always - sometimes a second eigenvalue is also negative). My question is now the following: Is there any mathematical interpretation for properties of the point $P$ where $\vec{v}_0$ and $\vec{F}$ are perpendicular?

I would really appreciate any ideas or helping hints for literature in this direction.

Cheers,

Hendrik

Comment: More precisely (at least for my understanding)  $\vec{F}_P^{m} = \vec{F} - 2(\vec{F}\cdot \vec{v}_0)\vec{v}_0$ expresses the fact that $\vec{F}_P^{m}$ is symmetrical of $\vec{F}$ with respect to hyperplane normal to $\vec{v}_0$.